# xtext and ace web editor code generation failed communication

Tags: xtext, ace-editor

I'm using the `Invoking Services` section from [xtext web editor support with ace](https://eclipse.dev/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html):

```js
var editor = xtext.createEditor();
$("#save-button").click(function() {
    // editor.xtextServices.saveResource();
    editor.xtextServices.generate();
});
```

I'm using the default `Greeting` grammar, and want to enable the default code generation:

```
// filename: <MyLovaelyDslName>Generator.xtend

class Phase0Generator extends AbstractGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(
        Resource resource,
        IFileSystemAccess2 fsa,
        IGeneratorContext context
    ) {
        fsa.generateFile('greetings.txt', 'People to greet: ' + 
            resource.allContents
                .filter(Greeting)
                .map[name]
                .join(', '))
    }
}
```

When I inspect the `GET` requests in the browser I see (10 requests like):

```
GET http://localhost:8080/xtext-service/generate?resource=67e22793.veri&requiredStateId=-7ffffff4 404 (Not Found)
```

followed by:

```
Xtext service 'generate' failed: Xtext service request failed after 10 attempts.
xtext-ace.js:1114 Xtext service 'generate' failed: Not Found
```

What am I missing in the `ace-xtext` communication? (Syntax highlights + custom validations I wrote work perfect)

**EDIT**

I found this part in the documentation:

> The usual way to include the Xtext servlet in a server application is to create a subclass of XtextServlet, override init() and destroy() to manage the runtime resources, and add a WebServlet annotation with urlPatterns = "/xtext-service/*" as parameter. See MyXtextServlet for an example

When I add override `doGet` in this subclass, I manage to intercept all requests and can delegate all non-`generate` requests to the `super`. But still, I don't have a clue how to get to the `generate` relevant method:

```java
@WebServlet(name = "XtextServices", urlPatterns = "/xtext-service/*")
public class Phase0Servlet extends XtextServlet {
    public void init() throws ServletException { /* ... */ }
    public void destroy() { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse response
    ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        var service = getService(req);
        var serviceType = <omitted>.getParameter("serviceType");
        if (serviceType.equals("generate")) { /* ... */ }
        else                                { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: i propose you debug the server

Comment: @ChristianDietrich yes, I made some progress (wrote above as EDIT). But I suspect I'm missing something in the setup because I can't seem to stitch the pieces together (the GET request to reach the correct place)

Comment: does this mean the backend is not reached at all? did you compare e.g. with what example in xtext codebase does: /org.eclipse.xtext.web.example.jetty/src/main/webapp/ace-statemachine-resource.html

Comment: @ChristianDietrich the link was a great help ! I must have missed the fact that the single line in the `*.html` was all I needed ... If you think it can help other users, you can write this as a short answer and I can direct the bounty to this answer.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom i think you shouldn't subclass `XtextServelt`. The servlet is used to bind the stateless server components to an HTTP endpoint. To participate in the dispatching, you should use the `org.eclipse.xtext.web.server.DefaultWebModuleFragment`